# top 5 values with join (higher number of clicks)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have 2 tables:
F_Test
and d_partners
I need to provide to every “site_name” the top 5 “partner_name” (by join with dim_partners) with the highest number of clicks (every record with value under the “partner_id” it’s one click).

This is my query:

```
select t.partner_name, t.partner_id
from F_Test as t, d_partners as t2
where t. partner_id =t2.partner_id
GROUP BY t.site_name
Order by desc limit 5
```

Do you think it's fine? What should I change?

Here are the parts of the tables:

F_Test table
[image: F_Test table]

d_partners table
[image: d_partners table]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: mysql version??

Comment: *Do you think it's fine?* - not quite. *What should I change?* - use MySQL 8 and do a row_number with a site name partition and a count(*)desc orderby, then take where rownumber<6 in an outer query

Comment: Thank you I'll try to write this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect a query like this:

```
select sp.*
from (select t.site_name, p.partner_name, count(*) as num_clicks,
             row_number() over (partition by t.site_name order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from F_Test t join
           d_partners p
           on p.partner_id = t.partner_id
      group by t.site_name, p.partner_name
     ) sp
where seqnum <= 5;
```

Notes:

- The query uses proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- As a corollary:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Use meaningful table aliases -- abbreviations for the table names -- rather than meaningless aliases.
- Window functions have been available in MySQL for several years, starting with version 8.0.

Comment: row_number() over partition by t.site_name order by count(num_clicks) desc) as seqnum. Can I count just the num_clicks? Why should I count everything? (*) because it's counting the rows, so it makes no difference?

Comment: @d12 . . . The question says that a row is a click, so this just counts rows.